# Existentially quantified type class

Tags: haskell

What is the type-class equivalent to the following existentially quantified dictionary, inspired by the `Pipe` type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, PolymorphicComponents #-}

data PipeD p = forall cat . PipeD {
    isoI        :: forall a b   m r . Iso (->) (p a b m r) (cat m r a b),
    categoryI   :: forall       m r . (Monad m) => CategoryI (cat m r)  ,
    monadI      :: forall a b   m   . (Monad m) => MonadI (p a b m)     ,
    monadTransI :: forall a b       . MonadTransI (p a b)               }
```

The rough idea I'm going for is trying to say that given the `(PipeLike p)` constraint, we can then infer `(MonadTrans (p a b), Monad (p a b m)` and (using pseudo-code) `(Category "\a b -> p a b m r")`.

The `CategoryI` and `MonadI` are just the dictionary equivalents of those type-classes that I use to express the idea that `Category`, `Monad`, and `MonadTrans` are (sort of) super-classes of this `PipeLike` type.

The `Iso` type is just the following dictionary storing an isomorphism:

```
data Iso (~>) a b = Iso {
    fw :: a ~> b ,
    bw :: b ~> a }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is indeed a type class, then the dictionary value is determined solely by the type `p`.  In particular, the type `cat` is determined solely by `p`.  This can be expressed using an *associated data type*.  In a class definition, an associated data type is written like a data definition without a right-hand side.

Once you express `cat` as a type, the other members can easily be changed to type classes, as I've shown for `Monad` and `MonadTrans`.  Note that I prefer to use explicit kind signatures for complicated kinds.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Pipe (p :: * -> * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *) where
  data Cat p :: (* -> *) -> * -> * -> * -> *
  isoI      :: forall a b m r. Iso (->) (p a b m r) (Category p m r a b)
  categoryI :: forall a b m.   Monad m => CategoryI (Category p m r)

instance (Pipe p, Monad m) => Monad (p a b m)

instance Pipe p => MonadTrans (p a b)
```

Comment: I think associated data types are probably the right direction, although I didn't want any dictionaries at all.  I was hoping for something like: `class (Monad (p a b m), MonadTrans (p a b), Category (Cat p)) => PipeLike p {- empty class -}`.  The isomorphism stuff was just glue to the existentially quantified type, which isn't necessary if I use the associated data type.

Comment: You can't make `Monad` and `MonadTrans` superclasses, because given `p`, there is no way to choose `a`, `b`, and `m`.  You can, however, make instances as I've shown.  They will work like the original interfaces.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for clearing my thoughts on this.  I'll accept this.

Comment: Aren't you more likely to want an associated type synonym than an associated data type?

Comment: @BenMilwood, I don't know which is more appropriate.  Since an existential type is explicitly packed and unpacked in data structures, I thought associated newtypes, with their explicit use of data constructors, would be closer to the original code than type synonyms.